# Tem problema incluir um pouco de bootstrap na página que está sem?

Tags: bootstrap

Olá, estou criando um sisteminha web e até o momento só criei o header e um sidebar com as opções. Até o momento estava criando tudo sem usar bootstrap, porém quero colocar elementos bootstrap como a section e as tabelas, já a que a criação do header e do sidebar me deram muito trabalho devido pouco conhecimento nas linguagens web. Gostaria de saber se há algum problema em continuar criando os outros elementos utilizando o bootstrap de forma que eu não tenha que recriar o header e sidebar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não há problema, isso é bastante habitual.

O que deves ter em conta é:

- páginas sem scripts é sempre preferível na perspetiva de velocidade e peso da página a carregar
- páginas com scripts são muitas vezes mais úteis pois podes interagir e ir mudando a página consoante o que o utilizador precisar
- usa sempre os mesmos scripts, nas páginas em que for possível, assim o browser carrega o script uma vez e não precisa de ir buscar na próxima
- usa versões minificadas em produção para manter o tamanho dos ficheiros o mais pequeno possível
- quando possível carrega os scripts `async`, isso diz ao browser que o script não é preciso para o carregamento da página assim a página é mostrada antes desse script carregar (nunca uses isto em CSS ou scripts que tenham de correr logo no inicio da página carregar)

Comment: Obrigado Sergio, tinha quase certeza de que não haveria problema, porém estava com medo de que isso poderia estar errado ou trazer problemas futuramente e obrigado pelas dicas também!